# Are there any SDKs for SharePoint REST APIs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am planning to call SharePoint REST APIs from my application server-side code to add files and add metadata.
I wanted to ask if there are any SDKs or libraries available for calling SharePoint REST APIs? I am ok with Java or .Net since we have not yet decided on the platform.
Also we are using SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

There is no SDK or library that was written as a wrapper for SharePoint REST API. If that's what you mean by SDK. I tried [writing something like that](https://github.com/Zerg00s/XSOM) 5 years ago, but abandoned this idea in favor of CSOM.

Now that we can use CSOM from .net Core, I see very little use for pure SharePoint REST when working with C#.